# Java Swing Multiple ActionListeners

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to keep actions separate as possible but am coming across the problem of an action firing off before the other. Right now I have a button that has two action listeners added.

```
JButton button = new JButton ();
...
button.addActionListener (new Action1 ());
button.addActionListener (new Action2 ());
```

2 is happening before 1. How can I guarantee the order? Is there a way to have an action that triggers other actions?

Comment: Well You can use method calls in any order you want inside ActionListener.

Comment: Create a third `Action` which takes a reference to `Action1` and `Action2`, apply this third `Action` to the button.  When triggered, it will call `Action1` and `Action2` in the order you want

Comment: I see you're new to SO

If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, event sources make no guarantees about the order in which listeners are notified. And that is for a reason: the pattern/concept is about decoupling the listener code, i.e. listeners should be independent of each other.

If `Action1` and `Action2` really need to coordinate their work, the code should not be spread in two places.

Answer (score 3):

If the two actions are dependent in their order, then it is functionally one action. I would only register the first actionlistener and call the second one directly from within the first one or - even better - write the code in one single actionlistener.

Comment: I probably am over thinking this but how do you fire off an action within an action?

Comment: @SunLightGirl99 `class MyAction extends AbstractAction { Action subAction = ... ; public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { subAction.actionPerformed(e); } }`

Comment: @SunLightGirl99 Why do you want to fire off an action? Normally you want to do this or want Java Swing to do this so that this action is handled asynchronously to your Swing-GUI. But here in your first actionListener you are already asynchronously to your gui - so what's wrong with directly calling the method of your second actionListener? I think there is no need to fire an action instead of calling the method directly!